# ML Units exceed the allowed maximum

Tags: google-cloud-platform, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

When I'm trying to submit a job for training a model in Google Cloud-ML, I'm getting the below error.

```
RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Quota failure for project my_project.
The requested 16.536900000000003 ML Units exceed the allowed maximum of 15.To read more about Cloud ML Engine quota, see https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/quotas.
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.QuotaFailure
  violations:
  - description: The requested 16.536900000000003 ML Units exceed the allowed maximum
  of 15.
subject: my_project
```

Now my question is, will this quota reset after few hours or days? Or do I need to ask for an increase in ML Units? If so, how to do that?

Comment: We had an issue in our quota system from yesterday and it has been fixed today. If you used to be able to submit jobs with similar configuration, then you might be impacted by the quota issue, and please try again. Otherwise, please reach out to us to increase the quota.

Comment: Thannks for the info.. It's resolved now. :)

Answer (score 0):

lleo@'s answer is correct; [this section](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/quotas#limits_on_concurrent_ml_training_units_and_prediction_nodes) states the following:

> The typical project, when first using Cloud ML Engine is limited in
>   the number of concurrent processing resources:
>
> - Concurrent number of ML training units: 15.

But to directly answer your question: that is a per-job quota (not something that "refills" after a few hours or days). So the immediate solution is to simply submit a job with fewer workers.

Having access to limited resources with new projects is pretty common on Google Cloud Platform, but you can email cloudml-feedback@google.com to see if you're eligible for an increase.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Guoqing Xu in comments, there was an issue. Which is resolved from their side and I can submit my job successfully now.

For me, there was only one job and that too it's light. Moreover there are no parallel computations going on. Hence, I was puzzled why the quota has reached.

It's resolved now, working fine. Thanks Google team for resolving it. :)

Answer (score -1):

You can read about default limits here [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/quotas)
You may ask for increasing the quota (on the API Manager page in the console). It looks like your issue is about concurrent ML units used, so you might either refactor your training pipeline or ask for a increased quota.